# disabling controls via checkbox in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I currently have 4 textboxes, 1 checkbox and a dropdownlist. I am attempting to disable the textboexes and dropdownlist upon 
the checkbox being checked. My current code does not work, but I can't seem to find the error in it. I am new to using JavaScript.

```
function enableCheckBox(phyAddressCheckBox, tb1, tb2, tb3, file1, tb4)
{
    if (document.getElementById(phyAddressCheckBox).checked) 
{
document.getElementById('tb1').enabled = true;
document.getElementById(tb2).enabled = true;
document.getElementById(tb3).enabled = true;
document.getElementById(file1).enabled = true;
document.getElementById(tb4).enabled = true;
}
else
{
document.getElementById(tb1).enabled = false;
document.getElementById(tb2).enabled = false
document.getElementById(tb3).enabled = false;
document.getElementById(file1).enabled = false;
document.getElementById(tb4).enabled = false;
}
}
```

edit
I set all property to disabled on both conditions and nothing works.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function enableCheckBox(phyAddressCheckBox, tb1, tb2, tb3, file1, tb4)
{
    if (document.getElementById(phyAddressCheckBox).checked) 
{
    document.getElementById('tb1').disabled = 'disabled';
document.getElementById(tb2).disabled = 'disabled';
document.getElementById(tb3).disabled = 'disabled';
document.getElementById(file1).disabled = 'disabled';
document.getElementById(tb4).disabled = 'disabled';
}
else
{
document.getElementById(tb1).disabled = 'disabled';
document.getElementById(tb2).disabled = 'disabled';
document.getElementById(tb3).disabled = 'disabled';
document.getElementById(file1).disabled = 'disabled';
document.getElementById(tb4).disabled = 'disabled';
}
}
</script>
```

I also added in the control code.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="phyAddressCheckBox" runat="server"  onclick="enableCheckBox(this.ID, physicalAddressTextbox, PhysicalAddress2Textbox, CityTextbox, physicalStateDropDownList,physicalZipTextbox)" style="text-align: left" />
```

Comment: Is your problem the fact that you're quoting your `tb1` argument?

Comment: i changed it and the correction did nothing as well

Comment: Show your errors. You're not describing what is not working. Even better create a http://jsfiddle.net and post it here

Comment: When the checkbox is checked, the textboxes and fildropdownlist are still enabled.

Comment: Is there an error on the console? Read my answer, I'm pretty sure you'll find the problem reading my suggestions and the code I posted on http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/7ZEvk/2/

Comment: The reason your code doesn't work is still because you're trying to call `document.getElementById('tb1')` instead of `document.getElementById(tb1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disagree with the people telling you to use `disabled='disabled'` The disabled property on input elements takes a boolean, unlike the HTML attribute. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLInputElement

From the names of the variables you're passing into `enableCheckBox`, it looks like you're passing DOM nodes instead of ids.

Another problem is that you're passing `this.ID`, you should be passing `this.id`. Even better, just pass the element itself. See this example http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/7ZEvk/2/

The last problem (in initial example) was that you were trying to set an `enabled` property, but that doesn't exist. You have to set the `disabled` property.

HTML

```
<input type='checkbox' id='cbox' onclick="enableCheckBox(this, 'text1', 'text2', 'text3', 'sel');"/>

<input id='text1' />
<input id='text2' />
<input id='text3' />
<select id='sel'>
    <option>hello</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript

```
// This is a lot like your function, but is less repetitive
function enableCheckBox(cbox /*, ... ids of fields to enable/disable */){    
    for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById(arguments[i]).disabled = cbox.checked;
    }
}
```

Comment: What i was referencing were not the same.

Comment: @MasterP: Huh? What's not the same as what?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
document.getElementById(tb1).disabled='disabled';
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558485/why-does-disabled-true-for-html-work

Comment: The disabled property takes true or false. The HTML attribute takes the string. I've never had a problem with setting `disabled = true or false` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLInputElement

Comment: Personally, I'd use jQuery and set the attribute: $(tb1).attr('disabled','disabled').

Comment: You can use whatever you'd like. But you need to tell us why.

Comment: disabled='disabled' is needed to make valid XHTML. <input disabled> is not valid, but <input disabled='disabled'> is.

Comment: You're not setting HTML attributes when doing `input.disabled`, you're changing DOM node properties. Also, disabled is valid, HTML5 is not XHTML. Even in the HTML, http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.checkbox.html tells you that disabled without a value is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0):

use the disabled property:

```
document.getElementById(tb1).disabled = 'disabled';
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `removeAttribute`  and `setAttribute`, when there is a `disabled` it is `disabled` else the `element` is `enabled`. you can do it like

```
function enableCheckBox(phyAddressCheckBox, tb1, tb2, tb3, file1, tb4){
    if (document.getElementById(phyAddressCheckBox).checked){
       document.getElementById(tb1).removeAttribute("disabled");
       document.getElementById(tb2).removeAttribute("disabled");
       document.getElementById(tb3).removeAttribute("disabled");
       document.getElementById(file1).removeAttribute("disabled");
       document.getElementById(tb4).removeAttribute("disabled");
    }else{
       document.getElementById(tb1).setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
       document.getElementById(tb2).setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
       document.getElementById(tb3).setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
       document.getElementById(file1).setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
       document.getElementById(tb4).setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
   }
}
```